# Check for falsy values on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeof, falsy

I don't understand why this piece of code works can someone explain to me?

If I delete this piece of the conditional `&& arr[i]` the value of `arr[5]` don't assume as a falsy value, but if I write that piece of code already assumes `arr[5]` like a falsy value.

You can see the value of `arr[5]` on the end of the function.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  let word = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (typeof arr[i] !== Boolean && arr[i]) {
      word.push(arr[i])
    }
  return word;
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Comment: With `i < arr.length` you specify to go until position 4 not 5.. if you want to go until pos 5, you need to say `i <= arr.length`.. below or equal with pos 5

Comment: In the code snippet you shared, I can't find a opening and closing brace for for loop

Comment: @MaraBlack Arrays are zero-based. The last element is at `arr.length - 1`. If you change the condition to `<= arr.length` you're out of bounds because `arr[arr.length]` doesn't exist

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem? Your script works exactly as expected. None of the values is truthy, hence with the `&& arr[i]` check the result is empty (check the length of the result). If you remove that check the result will only miss the first element because that's the only actual boolean.

Comment: @ShijuNambiar They are "optional". If you don't use them, then the next statement will be part of the loop, but nothing else. The function is actually: `let word = []; for ( ... ) { if ( ... ) { ... } } return word;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code if you want to check for falsy values

Let me tell you that falsy values don't require to be boolean!

For Example, 0 is a falsy value however typeof(0) is number ..

The reason why your code returns an empty array is the if condition, you're checking if typeof(arr[i]) !== Boolean && arr[i]

this condition will always be false since typeof returns a string and Boolean is considered as an Object/ Constructor (which isn't a string)

```
function bouncer(arr) {
  let word = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i]) {
      word.push(arr[i])
    }
  return word;
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe You can do it simplier :-)

```
let arr = [false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, "", 111, "aaa"];

let x = arr.filter(i => (typeof i !== Boolean && i))
```

[image]

Comment: What have you changed? Why? And why does this solve OPs problem (which is understanding the behavior of the script)?

Comment: `typeof` returns a string. You compare a string with a type (`typeof i !== Boolean`). Why should this work (hint: it doesn't)?

Comment: If I see code like this I alwayt try to suggest use of simplier solution just for educational purpose

Comment: @Andreas numeric and string are for testcase only -)

Comment: `typeof i` with `false` -> `"boolean"`. How is `"boolean" !== Boolean` going to do anything useful?

Comment: @Andreas If You don't understand, i just do some refactor to show simplier solution of source code in this question and i think author and community should have some benefit from it

Comment: Your answer doesn't work. _"i think author and community should have some benefit from it"_ - What's the benefit of non-working code?

Comment: it checking non falsy values result is `[ 111, 'aaa' ]` this is only example of course, tested on NodeJs, and in chrome console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242238/discussion-between-marek-lisiecki-and-andreas).